# PostgreSQL query with conditional empty values depending on preceding rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a postgresql query that i am not sure how to produce the output.

Lets say i have a sql query whose output i want is

```
         name    date     visit_number  visit
          x    2011-01-01     123         ??   (value i want=1)
          y    2011-01-01     123         ??   (value i want=empty)
          a    2011-02-02     345         ??   (value i want=1) 
          b    2011-02-02     345         ??    (empty)
          c    2011-02-02     345         ??     (empty)
```

currently my sql query contains all the values except the last column visit. I want the visit column to work this way...if visit_number contains same value for multiple rows, i want the column visit to show the value 1 for the first row and just null or empty for the remaining rows where the visit_number is the same. How do i do that???

i could write the sample query in any way.it could simply be :

```
    select name,date,visit_number from sometable order by date;
```

I am using postgres 8.1 version.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what is your current sql query?

Comment: Mr E..you could write it anyway....for example simply select name,date,visit_number from sometable; i would like to add this new column visit whose result should be what i described above

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post your current query!

Comment: We need to see your table structure and your current query in order to help you.

Comment: Please let me know if you need further information that what is provided. Thanks

Comment: You should really, **really** upgrade to a supported version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is upgrade to a modern day version of PostgreSQL. [Version 8.1 has reached end of life in November 2010](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

In a more recent version you can conveniently solve this with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT name, date, visit_number
     , CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY visit_number
                                    ORDER BY date, name) = 1
          THEN 1
          ELSE NULL
       END AS visit
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date, name;
```

I ordered by name additionally to break ties.

---

For versions before PostgreSQL 8.4, this query should work (untested):

```
SELECT name, date, visit_number
     , CASE WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   tbl t1
         WHERE  t1.visit_number =  tbl.visit_number -- more to make it unique?
         AND    t1.date <= tbl.date -- or more columns to make order unambiguous
         AND    t1.name <  tbl.name
         )
       THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS visit
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date, name;
```

Comment: I understand. I am an oracle guy and that was the first thought that came to my mind (using partition/window). Infact i even tried to run the query that way and then realized that the version does not support. Unfortunately right now, i cant do anything about upgrade as its not in my hands.

Comment: @cableload: I added a "vintage" solution for the desperate souls that are stuck with ancient versions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
select *, 
  case when row_number() over (partition by visit_number) = 1
    then 1
    else null
  end
from t
```

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/46e6a/1)

**Edit:**

Without window function:

```
select t4.*, case when t3.name is not null then 1 end as visit from t t4
left join (
  select t1.* from t t1
  left join t t2 on t1.name > t2.name and t1.date = t2.date and 
    t1.visit_number = t2.visit_number
  where t2.name is null
) as t3
on t3.name = t4.name and t3.date = t4.date and t3.visit_number = t4.visit_number
```

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bcdd7/1)

NOTE: If `name` is a key then the last comparison `t3.date = t4.date and t3.visit_number = t4.visit_number` can be removed